# Working on vb6 project remotely

Tags: vb6

I don't know if it is possible or not.. I just wanted to work on a vb6 project remotely. For instance, My friend is working on a vb6 project. and I want to work on that project from my computer. But we are only connected to each other via internet. Is it possible to work on a same vb6 project file from local machine and a remote access also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same project file? No, it can't be open in two places at once.

But you can do like every other developer in the world and use a version control system. There are lots of free options available online, like [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), [GitHub](https://github.com/), and [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/home).

What you do is create an account on one of those sites, upload your code to the website, and then you and your coworker can each check out a copy of the source. Whenever you make a significant change, you upload your changes back to the website, and your coworker can update his local copy with the new changes (or vice versa).

Of course, there are lots of different options for version control systems: Git, Mercurial (Hg), and Subversion (SVN) just to name a few. You'll need to do some research online to compare the advantages and disadvantages of each, and see which one you prefer.

I believe all of the sites I linked to have a "how to" or "getting started" guide that you will probably find rather useful.

Comment: Should I use them for vs 2010 projects too, or there is another better option for vs 2010?

Comment: Good for anything, from VB 6 to VS 2010.